# Variable Comparison vs Variable Declaration for Code Efficiency in PHP

Tags: php, performance

I have the below code and was wondering which approach is quicker for the PHP compiler. The variable declaration always assigns the value, but loses the check. Whereas the check only has the variable declaration when `$checked` evaluates as false.

**Variable Declaration**

```
$checked = false;
if($checkA == true){
    $checked = true;
}
if($checkB == true){
    $checked = true;
}
if($checkC == true){
    $checked = true;
}
```

**Variable Comparison**

```
$checked = false;
if($checkA == true){
    if(!$checked){
        $checked = true;
    }
}
if($checkB == true){
    if(!$checked){
        $checked = true;
    }
}
if($checkC == true){
    if(!$checked){
        $checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well put simply, the second sample with the completely unnecessary inner if is less efficient due to there being 2 if's for each test.

Comment: More concise would be `$checked = ($checkA || checkB || checkC)

Comment: Also if you are worrying about micro performance improvments at this level, you are probbaly wasting a lot of time for almost zero gain

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was curiosity more than anything, any improvement is worth it right? :)

Answer (score 1):

In best cases, they both are the same (3 executions with comparisation exluding jumps).
in worse cases, the first one is more performant (6 vs 7 executions)

but best would be

```
$checked = false;
if($checkA || $checkB || $checkC){
    $checked = true;
}
```

In all cases, this is a very negligeable performance issue. the gain is so small 1/1000000000 s